# TypeScript "import { myVar }" syntax seems to be incorrectly compiling in a Node/CommonJS/ES5 app

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In my Node application, I have a settings file that exports some settings as an object like this:

```
// settings.ts
export var settings = {
    port: 1234
}
```

In another file, I import these settings and attempt to reference the `port` property:

```
// another-file.ts
import { settings } from './settings';
console.log(settings.port);
```

This code compiles correctly, but at runtime I get the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'port' of undefined
```

When I inspect the compiled code, I can see that this is happening because my second file above is compiling to this:

```
var settings_1 = require("./settings");
console.log(settings_1.settings.port);
```

If I walk through the compiled code with my debugger, I can see that the `settings_1` variable points to the exported value from `settings.ts`.  In other words, my `port` property lives at `settings_1.port`, *not* at `settings_1.settings.port`.  It seems the TypeScript compiler should instead generated this JavaScript code:

```
var settings = require("./settings");
console.log(settings.port);
```

**Am I doing something wrong?  Or is the TypeScript compiler incorrectly compiling my import?**

I know that the TypeScript compiler is correctly type-checking my import; if I do something like this:

```
import { settings } from './settings';
console.log(settings.propertyThatDoesNotExist);
```

I get compiler errors that `propertyThatDoesNotExist` doesn't exist.

I'm using TypeScript 2.3.2, targeting "es5" and outputting "commonjs" modules, running on Node 6.9.2.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but your code seems right to me. Perhaps it'd be worth raising this on TypeScript's GitHub issue tracker?

Comment: The compiled import code looks fine, but what does the compiled export code look like? Judging from the typescript code, it should indeed provide a module object with a `.settings` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.  It was a silly mistake on my part (isn't it always?).  I was working on converting an application from JavaScript to TypeScript, and I copied and renamed `settings.js` to `settings.ts`... but I didn't delete `settings.js`.  As a result, I was *actually* importing my old `settings.js` file which had its exports set up differently.

Once I deleted `settings.js`, my application started correctly using the `.ts` file instead, and my imports worked as expected.